# Why do I consider in this circuit diagram that \$I_C = I_E\$ (BJT Transistor)

Tags: bjt

Consider follows problem on picture below:
Data diagram:

\$V = 20V \pm 20\%\$

\$I_{Carga} = 5A\$

\$\beta_1=2,\quad\beta_2=50\$

\$V_{diode} = 0.5V\$ (each)

\$V_{zener} = 10V,\quad I_{reserve\cdot zener} = 50mA\$

So find the value \$R\$?

I compute this problem on 2 differents strategies.

One was consider that

\$i_{e1} = (1+\beta_1)\cdot i_{b1}\quad(I)\$

and

\$5 = i_{e2} = (1+\beta_2)\cdot i_{b2}\quad(II)\$

as \$\quad i_{b2} = i_{e1}\$

\$i_{b1} = \dfrac{5}{(1+\beta_1)\cdot (1+\beta_2) }\$

Consider worse case to Voltage source (\$V = 18V\$)

\$i_R = 50mA+i_{b1}\Rightarrow\dfrac{18-(10+2\cdot0.5)}{R} = 50mA + \dfrac{5}{3\cdot 51}\Rightarrow \boxed{R = 85\Omega}\$

(**Letter E**)

But if I consider \$ i_c = i_e\$ (this problem consider that It is correct strategy)

We got: \$i_R = 50mA+i_{b1}\Rightarrow\dfrac{18-(10+2\cdot0.5)}{R} = 50mA + \dfrac{5}{2\cdot 50}\Rightarrow \boxed{R = 70\Omega}\$

(**Letter B**)

Like you see the Question 39 answer key show [Letter B is correct](https://arquivos.qconcursos.com/prova/arquivo_gabarito/62654/fundatec-2019-prefeitura-de-gramado-rs-engenheiro-eletricista-gabarito.pdf?_ga=2.232368543.1885084379.1574426158-1540062316.1568993417).

So, Why the first strategy is wrong (or not) and the second is the correct form of resolution?

[image]

Comment: Well, the exact solution will look like this: R_min = (18V - 11V)/(5A/153 + 50mA) = 84.66Ω, And if we decide to use a resistor from E24 series we have: 82Ω or 75Ω. But if we use a simplified approach Ie = Ic (Ic/Ie = β/(β +1) ≈ 1) we have R_min = (18V - 11V)/(5A/100 + 50mA) = 70Ω so this time we have 68Ω or 75Ω (from E24 series). And R_max = (22V - 11V)/(5A/153 + 50mA)  = 133Ω or R_max = (22V - 11V)/(5A/100 + 50mA) = 110Ω

Comment: So, there is something wrong with the answers.

Comment: Idk about the transistor \$T1\$. Because the \$ \beta_1\$ is too low is this on saturated mode? If I dont see wrong the \$T2\$ has \$V_{base} = 11V\$ and \$V_c = 18V\$ so it is on active region.

Comment: No, T1 is not in saturation. Why? Because the Vce1, in this case, will be around (18V - (11V - 2Vbe) ) ≈ 8.2V.

Comment: I would think just because the gain of current (beta) is slow in this case.